# In Julia, how iterate over Dataframe columns and names?

Tags: dataframe, iterator, julia

You can iterate over the columns with:

```
for c in eachcol(dataframe)
   ...
end
```

where `c` is the vector of values in that column.

How can I iterate and get both the name of the column and the values in that column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (name, col) in pairs(eachcol(dataframe))
    ...
end
```